# How to write a Python script to download file from the link that starts downloading automatically when clicked?

Tags: python

I have a link: https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/exp/voiProductDetailsViewExport.ctl?media=xls&tradeDate=20220114&reportType=F&productId=425

If you copy this url and paste it to the browser, .xls file will start downloading

How to write a Python script to download the .xls file programmatically? So I can run .py file to download .xls file

If it was a link pointing to the file directly e.g. "http://google.com/favicon.ico" then it would be straightforward, something like:

```
import requests
url = 'http://google.com/favicon.ico'
r = requests.get(url)
open('google.ico', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

but since my link is not just the link to the file, this solution doesn't work

Please help to write the Python script to download the .xls file from the following link https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/exp/voiProductDetailsViewExport.ctl?media=xls&tradeDate=20220114&reportType=F&productId=425

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the current day date from the DateTime module and strip that out with strftime and change your URL like this:

```
from datetime import date
import requests

today = date.today()
todayStr= date.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
url = "https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/exp/voiProductDetailsViewExport.ctl?media=xls&tradeDate="+todayStr+"&reportType=F&productId=425"

r = requests.get(url)
open(todayStr+'.xls', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: Thank you @m.hatami for looking into this! Maybe I wasn't clear enough when asking the question, but the problem is not to get the current/today date in the "tradeDate" query param. The problem is that when I try to download the file from that link using Python - nothing happens. So, if I run .py file with your script, the '.xls' file doesn't download

Comment: hi, I tested it and it works.
what error do you get when you run it??

Comment: I copied your script into "download.py" file and when I run the command:
` python3 download.py ` the cursor is just goes into the next line, but nothing happens, like it just hangs (I am using python 3.9.9 version, hope it doesn't matter. I also have requests module installed).

For instance, If I try the following code (from my post above):
`
import requests
url = 'http://google.com/favicon.ico'
r = requests.get(url)
open('google.ico', 'wb').write(r.content)
`
it runs fine and I can see "google.ico" next to "download.py"

Comment: I am fairly new with Python, so if there is something I am missing, please let me know. Thanks again @m.hatami for trying to help!

Comment: @AlekseiMiasin I think in this case you have to debug using breakpoints and find out where the problem is and also you can try testing this script in another system

Comment: I just had to include headers in "requests.get" and everything worked!